# Understanding a SMD Motor driver IC (heat dissipation and control)

Tags: 3.3v, motordriver

I am designing a circuit to control a 12V, 3A electric pump. I thought the driver `rz7899` is very handy.

The [datasheet](http://www.rz-mic.com/uploadfile/fj/201810310633.pdf) gave me the following doubts.

1. Is it compatible with the 3.3V micro controller? I have this doubt because ViH can go as big as the operating voltage.
2. Is this SMD required to dissipate a 3W power during full load operation? I ask this because it shows when 6V is applied at VCC, we can expect a 5.5V at the output. Scaling this to 12V, it will be 11V at the output when 12V is applied to VCC. So, at full load, I will be required to dessipate a 3W power.
3. What does the "auxiliary heat dissipation" mean? It is mentioned in the table of Electrical Characteristics.

Comment: Why did you accept an incorrect answer?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, I am sorry. I thought that is a right answer. Let me check again.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Is it compatible with the 3.3V micro controller?

What a poor data sheet! Are logic levels independent of Vcc? It is likely that logic **low** is compatible with a 3.3V micro controller. But what about logic **high**? Logic levels are spec'd at only one Vcc of +6V:
[image: data sheet fragment: logic levels]

It could be that logic high is nominally half of Vcc. Or it could be that logic high is nominally 3V, independent of Vcc. I'd guess the latter is true, but I'd test it to see if changing Vcc also changes logic input threshold.
 Note that you cannot use this chip when Vcc < 3.0 V. Although not stated, you likely shouldn't present a logic input greater than Vcc (+6V in this case).

> 2. Is this SMD required to dissipate a 3W power during full load operation?

It will dissipate less than 3W with a light load, and should be run this way. The thermal characteristics are not well specified. Note that ambient temperature may not exceed +85C.

OP scaling is likely incorrect. At Vcc=6V, Iout=3A:  Voh=5.7V, Vol=0.15V.... That's about 1.35W power dissipation. I'd hope that this dissipation also applies when you raise Vcc to +12V.
Dissipation seems tied to current output (It claims internal current-limiter circuits). For resistive loads, raising Vcc will also raise current in a proportional way. Don't exceed 3A.

> 3. What does the "auxiliary heat dissipation" mean?

It means that considerable printed circuit board copper is required to reach the 3A continuous operation. Again, very poorly specified.

Comment: Read the ViH spec again, 1st answer is incorrect

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 What an ambiguous data sheet!

Comment: True of most highly effective Asian chips. You have to know how they work before reading it.IP protection by minimal info.

Answer (score 3):

This is a wonderful FET full bridge motor driver with 50m\$\Omega\$ low and 100m high side driver nom.

1. It can be operated from Vdd logic from 2.2V to 6V with a typical input threshold of \$\dfrac{ViH min + ViL max}{2}= 1.45V\$.  Excess high/low  voltage is simply margin.
2. VHout min = 5.5 @ Io=3A, Vcc=6V means the Pch FET is worst case 500mV/3A= 167 mohms and yes that means during this direction fully on, it dissipates 1.5W hence why they use > 2 sqin of 2 oz double sided copper typically done for PCB heatsinks.
3. "Auxiliary heat dissipation" means you can reduce the chip rise by thermally coupling the gnd plane to a a heatsink or larger metal backplane or use a mini force air fan. This is common for CNC FET bridges commonly used by Arduino's and way of extending the life of the cap onboard.

Comment: If I use a VCC of 12V power supply, it is required to dissipate 3W, right?

Comment: Worst case yes and ground plane dissipate the heat at least 40’C rise on board ; verify Rth for your thermal design

Comment: The first point is valid only for the 6V case? Or also valid for 12V? I mean Does ViHmin, VILmax change with the VCC? Because above the table it is said that the VCC is 6V